# Create React App not showing error message with

Tags: node.js, reactjs, installation

npx : The term 'npx' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- npx create-react-app myapp
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (npx:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Comment: Please provide more information, also you can edit your question by pressing the Edit button right under it, you don't have to post your corrections as an answer. I think your problem may have to do with `npx` not being installed on your computer, this could be if you have never installed `node`. You can download it at https://nodejs.org

Answer (score 0):

**Create React App not showing error message with ErrorBoundary
npx : The term 'npx' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- npx create-react-app myapp
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (npx:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

**